# Subquery to pull single record by Max DateTime Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a subquery (MS SQL 2016) to pull the most recent measurement value for a specific measure.  I need to link the resulted measure value back to my main query by PAT_ID.  The problem I'm running into is that I can't get the MAX Date (most recent date) to pull only one record in the subquery.

The following query returns numerous records and not the most recent record only

```
    SELECT distinct meas.MEAS_VALUE, rec.pat_id, MAX(meas.ENTRY_TIME) "MAX ET"
    from ip_flwsht_rec rec
        inner join [CLARITY].[dbo].[IP_FLWSHT_MEAS] meas on rec.fsd_id=meas.FSD_ID 
            and meas.flo_meas_id='14' 
            and meas.MEAS_VALUE is not null
    where meas.ENTRY_TIME>=(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,getdate()) - 548, 0))
        AND rec.pat_id = 'CENSORED'
    GROUP BY meas.MEAS_VALUE, rec.PAT_ID
```

This returns the results...

[image: PAT_ID is censored to protect the innocent]

This same patient has 9 results but I only want the most recent.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your query seems confused to me because you are selecting `MEAS_VALUE`, but the join between the two tables involves the `FSD_ID` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, the `top 1` approach in @Zack's answer might be the best approach.  It features one of the most redeeming of all qualities, simplicity.

If the `top 1` approach does not satisfy your requirements, then you are pretty close.  In your question, you say, `I need to link the resulted measure value back to my main query by PAT_ID`.  Actually, you need to link it with two fields, the pat_id, and the entry_time.

To ensure you only get one record per patient, change this:

```
SELECT distinct meas.MEAS_VALUE, rec.pat_id, MAX(meas.ENTRY_TIME) "MAX ET"
```

to this:

```
SELECT rec.pat_id, MAX(meas.ENTRY_TIME) "MAX ET"
```

Your final query then resembles this:

```
with mostRecentRecords as (
select rec.pat_id, MAX(meas.ENTRY_TIME) mostRecentEntry
from etc
group by rec.pat_id
)
select whatever
from your tables
join mostRecentRecords on rec.pat_id = mostRecentRecords.pat_id
     and meas.entry_time = mostRecentEntry
```

Comment: Dan - That's exactly what I needed!

The "TOP 1" would meet the needs for testing individual patients but wouldn't work for all patients.  I was getting the extra rows without joining both fields (time and Pat_id) as you noted.  Much obliged!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add TOP(1) in your select, and sort it by time:

```
SELECT distinct TOP(1) meas.MEAS_VALUE, ...
...
ORDER BY meas.ENTRY_TIME DESC
```

Comment: This would work but I'll need to grab the top value for all patients in my main query and not the specific PAT_ID that I'm testing with.

Comment: Ok, that is different. In your question you are implying that 9 answers you get are the correct ones, and you just need the top one. You should update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to order the `meas` records prior to joining, and partitioned by `fsd_id`. Resulting in the latest record from `meas` for each `fds_id` without the need for `group by` or aggregation.

```
select
    meas.MEAS_VALUE
  , rec.pat_id
  , [Max ET] = meas.ENTRY_TIME
from ip_flwsht_rec rec
  inner join (
    select *
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by fsd_id order by ENTRY_TIME desc)
    from [CLARITY].[dbo].[IP_FLWSHT_MEAS]
    ) as meas 
        on rec.fsd_id=meas.FSD_ID 
       and meas.rn = 1 /* just the latest row based on `entry_time` */
       and meas.flo_meas_id='14' 
       and meas.MEAS_VALUE is not null
where meas.ENTRY_TIME>=(dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0,getdate()) - 548, 0))
    and rec.pat_id = 'CENSORED'
```

Comment: dont you miss `where rn = 1` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's in the join

Comment: I tried this and it took over two minutes to run, not to mention it returned the wrong result.  It appears to giving me the smallest measurement value instead of the value linked to the max date entry.